# template parameter for const iterator instead of iterator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator, constants

***Note***: I have written a "recipe" based on the lessons learnt from the exercise and the answers & comments on this page, see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029941/Python-like-enumeration-in-Cplusplus.

I'm playing around with the extensions that C++11 brings to C++03. I want to be able to iterate over a container using the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<int> list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    for (auto x : enumerated(list))
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    for (auto x : const_enumerated(list))
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
}
```

The first iteration has x modifiable, vs for the second, attempting to modify x would lead to a compile error. I have something that works for the non-const case:

```
template <typename Container>
class EnumerationAdaptor
{
public:
    EnumerationAdaptor(Container& container) : container_(container) {}
    EnumIter<typename Container::iterator> begin() const { return container_.begin(); }
    EnumIter<typename Container::iterator> end() const { return container_.end(); }

private:
    Container& container_;
};

template <typename Container>
EnumerationAdaptor<Container> enumerated(Container& container) { return container; }

template <typename Container>
EnumerationAdaptor<const Container> const_enumerated(const Container& container) { return container; }
```

The non-const case uses `EnumIter<std::list<...>::iterator>`, as desired, and I'm trying to make the const case use `EnumIter<std::list<...>::const_iterator>` as return type of `begin()` and `end()`. Seems like I need decltype:

```
template <typename Container>
class EnumerationAdaptor
{
public:
    EnumerationAdaptor(Container& container) : container_(container) {}
    EnumIter<decltype(Container().begin())> begin() const { return container_.begin(); }
    EnumIter<decltype(Container().end())> end() const { return container_.end(); }  // *** compile error (see below)

private:
    Container& container_;
};
```

But I get a compilation error in Visual Studio 2015 Express:

```
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 
'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>' 
to  
 'EnumIter<std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<int>>>>'
[in c:\users\...\enumeratedcpp.cpp line 46, which is line marked ***]
```

which suggests that I'm doing something wrong with decltype, as the compiler is finding the non-const begin(). Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT**: even with a simple EnumIter, problem is same:

```
template <typename Iter>
class EnumIter
{
public:
    EnumIter(Iter begin) : iter_(begin) {}

    EnumIter& operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const EnumIter& rhs)
    {
        return iter_ != rhs.iter_; // or self.index_ != rhs.index_;
    }

    int operator*() const
    {
        return index_;
    }

private:
    Iter iter_;
    int index_ = 0;
};
```

Comment: this is probably easier solved with a separate `ConstEnumerationAdaptor` that calls `cbegin` and `cend`

Comment: otherwise, try replacing `Container()` (inside the decltype) with `std::declval<Container&>()` (from <utility>)

Comment: actually, I think the problem might lie in `EnumIter<>`

Comment: I don't think problem is in EnumIter, I have given a simplified version of it that still produces the issue (i've edited the post). I know I could easily fix this with Const adapter (cbegin/cend -- tried it before posting) and/or template specialization to extract the correct iterator typedef, but I'd really like to know why decltype doesn't work as expected because there's less code.

Comment: @sp2danny declval works; i'll investigate further

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64bd4f3278202b1e

Comment: @sp2danny yes, similar to what I ended up with once I made use of std::declval. Note however, you don't need the & in declval, and the reference type is used only in EnumIter, so you don't need the second template parameter. Also, there is no need for trailing return type. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0aba6010b20f98e0. So some simple things are still too complicated with decltype: I can write `decltype(&Container::begin)` for "type of begin method", I should be able to write `decltype(&Container::begin())` for type of object returned by that overload of begin method.

Comment: @Schollii You do need the `&` in `declval` because you're holding your container as an lvalue and you don't want to use the wrong type in case there's an rvalue-ref-qualified overload.

Comment: `using iterator_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<Container>{}, typename Container::const_iterator, typename Container::iterator>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one issue with this expression:

```
decltype(Container().begin())
```

which is that `Container()` only works if `Container` happens to be default-constructible. That limits the usability of your class for no reason. (There is a lesser issue which is that this won't work for raw arrays, but that's another exercise).

Besides that, the code is perfectly valid for class types. From [expr.type.conv]:

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a non-array complete object
>   type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type [...]

So if `Container` is `const list<int>`, then the type of that whole expression should be `list<int>::const_iterator`. If MSVC gives you something else, that's a  bug.

That said, we really should address the default-constructibility issue. That's where [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) comes in:

```
decltype(std::declval<Container&>().begin())
```

This will not impose any restrictions on `Container`, and perhaps MSVC will handle this correctly.

Comment: "Second, the type of a constructor call is never cv-qualified. So `decltype(T())`, where valid, is the same as `std::remove_cv_t<T>`." [expr.type.conv]/p2 appears to suggest differently. And both GCC and Clang [preserves](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bfc2907fd219cc0) the cv-qualification.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah missed the non-class part the first time around. Hm. So why does OP's expression not work then?

Comment: MSVC bug, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Insightful, thanks. Well if true I learnt something due to a bug in compiler :) BTW at least in VC++ 2015, the & is not required in declval, nor does it seem like it would be required from the docs for that function, nor is it used in the example on cppreference.com, yet both you and sp2danny used it, what is reason?

Comment: @Schollii `declval<T>()` gives you an rvalue reference, `declval<T&>()` gives you an lvalue reference. If there's a `begin() &` and a `begin() &&`, the two could give you different types.

Comment: @Barry not sure what you mean: "const_iterator begin() const;" there is no & or &&. Can you give me an example of container that would fail (to compile, or run as expected) in my main() if I don't have the & in declval?